# How to relate models to markers in ARToolKit for Android?

Tags: android, artoolkit

I am new to ARToolKit and I have been using the SimpleNativeCars example for Android. I have trained a new marker and put it in the assets folder and tried to relate it to my own model which is in my models folder. I have done this in the  ARWrapperNativeCars.cpp file like the other models and markers are but it does not recognise it. I have also tried changing the two sample models to their opposite marker but that still does nothing. I have searched this site and the web but cannot find an answer to this question. Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

Below is the method where I am trying to fix this.

Thanks.

```
#define NUM_MODELS 3
static ARModel models[NUM_MODELS] = {2};

static float lightAmbient[4] = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f};
static float lightDiffuse[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
static float lightPosition[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_DEMO(demoInitialise(JNIEnv* env, jobject object)) {

const char *model0file = "Data/models/Ferrari_Modena_Spider.obj";
const char *model1file = "Data/models/Porsche_911_GT3.obj";
const char *model2file = "Data/models/Keith.obj";

models[0].patternID = arwAddMarker("single;Data/patt.hiro;80");
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[0].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_SQUARE_USE_CONT_POSE_ESTIMATION, false);
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[0].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_FILTERED, true);

models[0].obj = glmReadOBJ2(model0file, 0, 0); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
if (!models[0].obj) {
    LOGE("Error loading model from file '%s'.", model0file);
    exit(-1);
}
glmScale(models[0].obj, 0.035f);
//glmRotate(models[0].obj, 3.14159f / 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glmCreateArrays(models[0].obj, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);
models[0].visible = false;

models[1].patternID = arwAddMarker("single;Data/patt.kanji;80");
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[1].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_SQUARE_USE_CONT_POSE_ESTIMATION, false);
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[1].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_FILTERED, true);

models[1].obj = glmReadOBJ2(model1file, 0, 0); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
if (!models[1].obj) {
    LOGE("Error loading model from file '%s'.", model1file);
    exit(-1);
}
glmScale(models[1].obj, 0.035f);
//glmRotate(models[1].obj, 3.14159f / 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glmCreateArrays(models[1].obj, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);
models[1].visible = false;

models[2].patternID = arwAddMarker("single;Data/patt.job;80");
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[2].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_SQUARE_USE_CONT_POSE_ESTIMATION, false);
arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[2].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_FILTERED, true);

models[2].obj = glmReadOBJ2(model2file, 0, 0); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
if (!models[2].obj) {
    LOGE("Error loading model from file '%s'.", model2file);
    exit(-1);
}
glmScale(models[2].obj, 0.035f);
//glmRotate(models[1].obj, 3.14159f / 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glmCreateArrays(models[2].obj, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);
models[2].visible = false;
```

}

Comment: I have noticed my model's .mtl file is not found with the .obj file from the models folder when the app is run. It does find my marker file but does not load it when the app runs.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the Android project does some caching of the markers (at Application level) and other items under assets. The caching system is linked to the versionNumber on the Manifest, so increasing it should solve it, if that is the issue.

That was my problem when adding new markers, but I was not using NDK, so it may not be your case.

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not seem to help. I had known about the versionNumber in the Manifest but when I run the app I can see in the logcat that all items in my assets folder are cached. The issue I come up against is that once everything is cached and the native library is loaded it only seems to load the first two .patt files that come with the example. I will check the native libraries to see if I can find a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are updating your phones cache with the new .obj and .mtl files by increasing the build number by 1.

You can do this by going into the **build.gradle** file in the aRSimpleNativeCars module and increasing the number of the **versionCode** field under the defaultConfig section.

It seems your jniLibs are not being updated with your changes because your code seems to be working correctly.

You need to make sure you have the ndk-bundle installed (Android Studio latest version installs this for you inside the **C:\Users\"your user"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle** folder) and add it to your PATH environment variable.

This will allow you to run the **ndk-build** command in the **jni** folder inside the **aRSimpleNativeCars** module, updating the jniLibs.

SideNote: Since there is no support to debug the C++ code in Android Studio, I often use logs to check that my changes are made successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and all I did is **uninstalling the app** or **clearing app data** then run the app again.

There is also this [plugin](https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea) that helped me do it faster using the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A` (windows/linux) or `Ctrl+Shift+A` (OSX)

Also make sure that `ndk-build` command run successfully.